# Get user details using the authentication token in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, facebook, authentication, servicestack

I am using servicestack, in the clientside, i am having facebook authentication which will provide an accesstoken post logging in

```
 function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
```

Once authentication is done, a cookie value is setup `fbsr_Appid` which will contain the authentication token

When user makes request to servicestack, I will be able to fetch this authentication token from cookie value in context. **So now, how can i get the user ID/ email ID of the user using this token ?**

Currently i am able to fetch the the expiry time for the access token using the below url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token_info?client_id=APPID&access_token=xxxxxxxxx
```

Which returns response in below format

```
{
access_token: "xxxxxxxx",
token_type: "bearer",
expires_in: 5560
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i figured out a way to do that

```
var details = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}", token);
```

This is giving response in below format

```
{
id: "344657773358323",
email: "zz@gmail.com",
first_name: "xxxxxx",
gender: "male",
last_name: "xxxxxx",
link: "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxx/",
locale: "en_US",
name: "xxxx  xxxx",
timezone: 5.5,
updated_time: "xx-xx-xx:07:xx+0000",
verified: true
}
```